# Javascript passing variable and elementId to an function

Tags: javascript

```js
var ingaveA = {
  stuks: ""
};
var ingaveB = {
  prijs: ""
};
var uitgave = {
  totaal: ""
};

update(ingaveA, "testa", ingaveB, "testb", uitgave, "testc");

function update(refA, argsA, refB, argsB, refC, argsC) {

  refA.stuks = document.getElementById(argsA).value;
  refB.prijs = document.getElementById(argsB).value;
  refC.totaal = refA.stuks * refB.prijs;
  document.getElementById(argsC).value = refC.totaal;
}

ingaveA = ingaveA.stuks;
ingaveB = ingaveB.prijs;
uitgave = uitgave.totaal;
alert("Stuks=" + ingaveA + " Prijs=" + ingaveB + " Totaal=" + uitgave);
```

```html
<input id="testa" value="10">
<input id="testb" value="6">
<input id="testc" value="">
```

Is there an better way to do this? always 3 variable names and 3 elements.
Maybe using an array ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `document.getElementById()` for every input, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and `[id^=test]` to select all 3 and put them in a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (think of it as an array).

`[id^=test]` means every id that starts with `test`

You can also make one general object, and update it as needed like below.

```js
var ingave = {
  ingaveA: {
    stuks: ""
  },
  ingaveB: {
    prijs: ""
  },
  uitgave: {
    totaal: ""
  }
};
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=test]");

update(ingave, inputs);

function update(ref, inputs) {
  ref.ingaveA.stuks = inputs[0].value;
  ref.ingaveB.prijs = inputs[1].value;
  ref.uitgave.totaal = ref.ingaveA.stuks * ref.ingaveB.prijs;
  inputs[2].value = ref.uitgave.totaal;
}

var ingaveA = ingave.ingaveA.stuks;
var ingaveB = ingave.ingaveB.prijs;
var uitgave = ingave.uitgave.totaal;
alert("Stuks=" + ingaveA + " Prijs=" + ingaveB + " Totaal=" + uitgave);
```

```html
<input id="testa" value="10">
<input id="testb" value="6">
<input id="testc" value="">
```

Comment: ok this worked so far ,  but to send this ingave as POST to an php script i thought it is better to convert it to an array , so tried all , slice, call .... array.from ... any idea what would be better?

Comment: Do `var array = [ingaveA, ingaveB, uitgav];`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the question is here, but you don't need to create 3 separate objects.

```
let ingaveA = ""
let ingaveB = ""
let uitgave = ""
```

then just pass these 3 to your function:

```
function update(refA, refB, refC) {

  refA = document.getElementById("testa").value;
  refB = document.getElementById("testb").value;
  refC = refA * refB;
  document.getElementById("testc").value = refC.totaal;
}
```

Again, it's hard to optimize it as we don't know your specifics of the code.

Comment: Use mate , i need to send the input id of inputs to the function.